# How to Install pavucontrol without apt?

Tags: package-management, skype, debian

I need to install pavucontrol by hand, because my apt does not work. How can I install it by hand? I just need to get it for skype sound but my apt does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find pavucontrol on [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pavucontrol). You can install from deb (using software center) or the [tar.gz file](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/pavucontrol_0.9.9.orig.tar.gz) (manual; click to download).

But I would advice fixing apt.

Comment: I already got a .deb from the Ubuntu repo. Here is my [apt question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43001/apt-does-not-work-in-public-wifi)